# Why does the map induce an injection of function fields

Tags: field-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I was reading the book *Arithemtic of Elliptic curves* by Silverman and came across this

Let C1/K and C2/K be curves and let $\phi$ : C1 → C2 be a nonconstant rational map defined over K. Then composition with $\phi$ induces an injection of function fields
fixing K,

$$\phi^{*}:K(C_{2})\longrightarrow K(C_{1}),\ \ \  \ \ \phi^{*}f=f\circ\phi$$
Why is this an **injection**?

Comment: Every nonzero map from a field must be an injection. What could the kernel be?

Comment: Do you mean homomorphism of fields must be an injection?If that's the case I get it.Otherwise clearly $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ , $f(x)=x^2$ is a non zero map between fields that is not injective.So,$\phi^{*}$ must be a homomorphism of function fields for injection,right?

Comment: Yes, by "map" I mean "homomorphism", as I thought would be clear from the context of your question.

Comment: Alright then,got it.Thanks for the clarification.